# Как сменить формат даты при отправке ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl

Всем привет!
Как при отправке ajax запроса, либо при его получении обработчиком изменить формат даты?
input type="date" принимает дату в формате "Y-m-d".
Обработчик на выходе должен отправить запрос к API с датой в формате "d.m.Y".
Обработчик реализован с помощью curl php.

Comment: Смотрели документацию на `DateTime::format`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то как-то так

```
<?php

$date = $_POST['date'];
$requestDateTime = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
$resultDateTime  = $requestDateTime->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]